# Optimize MySQL query to find Duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I originally asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299113/speed-up-mysql-join-to-check-for-duplicates).

I'm using the following query to return all duplicate records with the same first and last name. The trick is that the contact_id, has to be in descending order.

Problem is that the database has a few million records in the "contacts" table. They queory takes several minutes to complete.

I have the contact_firstName, contact_lastName, contact_client_id, and contact_id all indexed in the database.

Any other ideas on how this query can be optimized a little further?

```
SELECT c.contact_id, c.contact_purl, c.contact_firstName, c.contact_lastName, c.contact_organization 
FROM (
        SELECT contact_purl, contact_firstName, contact_lastName, MIN(contact_id) AS MinID 
        FROM contacts 
        WHERE contact_client_id = 1 
        GROUP BY contact_purl HAVING COUNT(contact_id) > 1)  t 
INNER JOIN contacts c 
ON t.contact_purl = c.contact_purl  
AND c.contact_client_id = 1
AND t.MinID <> c.contact_id  
ORDER BY contact_id asc
```

EXPLAIN:
[image]

SCHEMA:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts` (
  `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contact_client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_sales_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_campaign_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_purl` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `contact_purl1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_purl2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_firstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contact_lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contact_organization` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_url_organization` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_position` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_fax` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `contact_address1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_address2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_state` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_zip` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_IP` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `contact_pw` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `contact_subscribed` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `contact_import` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_1` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_2` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_3` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_4` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_5` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_6` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_7` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_8` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_9` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_10` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_11` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_12` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_13` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_14` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_15` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_16` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_17` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_18` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_19` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_20` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_21` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_22` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_23` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_24` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_25` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_26` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_27` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_28` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_29` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_30` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_31` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_32` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_33` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_34` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_35` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_36` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_37` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_38` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_39` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_40` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_41` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_42` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_43` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_44` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_45` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_46` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_47` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_48` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_49` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_c_50` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_i_1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_i_2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_i_3` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_i_4` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_i_5` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_i_6` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_i_7` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_i_8` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_i_9` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_i_10` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_i_11` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_i_12` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_i_13` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_i_14` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacts_i_15` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contact_id`),
  KEY `contact_campaign_id` (`contact_campaign_id`),
  KEY `contact_client_id` (`contact_client_id`),
  KEY `contact_purl2` (`contact_purl2`),
  KEY `contact_purl1` (`contact_purl1`),
  KEY `contact_purl` (`contact_purl`)
)
```

Comment: Query plan and schema, please.

Comment: Quick tip: in MySQL, `GROUP BY` automatically applies `ORDER BY` because ... noone knows. To prevent this behavior to speed up your query a bit, add `ORDER BY NULL` to the grouped query.

Comment: I added the table schema and query plan (explain) to the question...

Answer (score 1):

You could do it simply making a join on itself, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.contact_id, c1.contact_firstName, c1.contact_lastName,
       RIGHT(c1.contact_lastName,1) AS nameNum
FROM
      contacts c1 INNER JOIN contacts c2
        ON c1.contact_firstName = c2.contact_firstName
       AND c1.contact_lastName  = c2.contact_lastName
       AND c2.contact_client_id = 1
       AND c1.contact_id <> c2.contact_id
ORDER BY c1.contact_id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Spaeth, however this took even longer to execute.  In the several minute range!

Answer (score 0):

Would it make sense to keep track of the number of contacts for each client separately and store it in another column vs doing that sub-select query every time?

With that number of records, it might be more efficient to store some of those calculations instead of having to query them in real time.